# Вопрос по с++, помеченный решенным, работает с ошибками

Tags: c++, stl, filestream

Занимался записью массива структур в двоичный файл. Наткнулся на "решенный" пример по ссылке [How to read / write a struct in Binary Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506645/how-to-read-write-a-struct-in-binary-files)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;


typedef struct student
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
    vector<int> grades;
}student_t;

int main()
{
    student_t apprentice[3];  
    strcpy(apprentice[0].name, "john");
    apprentice[0].age = 21;
    apprentice[0].grades.push_back(1);
    apprentice[0].grades.push_back(3);
    apprentice[0].grades.push_back(5);    

    strcpy(apprentice[1].name, "jerry");
    apprentice[1].age = 22;
    apprentice[1].grades.push_back(2);
    apprentice[1].grades.push_back(4);
    apprentice[1].grades.push_back(6);

    strcpy(apprentice[2].name, "jimmy");
    apprentice[2].age = 23;
    apprentice[2].grades.push_back(8);
    apprentice[2].grades.push_back(9);
    apprentice[2].grades.push_back(10);

    // Serializing struct to student.data
    ofstream output_file("students.data", ios::binary);
    output_file.write((char*)&apprentice, sizeof(apprentice));
    output_file.close();

    // Reading from it
    ifstream input_file("students.data", ios::binary);
    student_t master[3];
    input_file.read((char*)&master, sizeof(master));         

    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
    {
        // If you wanted to search for specific records, 
        // you should do it here! if (idx == 2) ...

        cout << "Record #" << idx << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << master[idx].name << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << master[idx].age << endl;
        cout << "Grades: " << endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < master[idx].grades.size(); i++)
           cout << master[idx].grades[i] << " ";
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

-- попробовал. Программа собирается нормально, но при запуске у меня(gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) выдает в конце: "free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Аварийный останов"

Вопрос - в чем суть проблемы и как это исправить? Буду очень благодарен конкретному ответу (если возможно, то с примером).

PS Успел нарыть следующее. Если в структуре заменить string на char [] и vector на int [] проблема уходит. Но четкого ответа не вижу (догадываюсь, что он связан с особенностями реализации контейнеров и их применения, поскольку речь идет о free(), которую я напрямую не юзаю. Глубже пока не понимаю.)  Немного обескураживает, что вопрос помечен как "решен".
PPS Я знаю, что есть Boost Serialization, но хочу этот пример докопать до сути уже.

Comment: Цитата из комментария под постом: "Downvoted, because "serializing" a std::vector this way is completely nonsense". А вообще там много интересного в комментариях.

Comment: да да, там в коментарях прям и говорят, что это сломанное решение, оно и на вид выглядит дико (особенно объявление структуры). Но оно в плюсе. Да, и на английской версии бывают такие ужасы

Comment: @KoVadim да - прочитал. Меня сбило, что 28 раз как "решен". Спасибо.

Comment: я понял, почему оно "решено и заплюсовано". потому что вначале автор написал буст решение, а потом уже свое "сломанное ручное".

Comment: @KoVadim нет слов :-)

Comment: Издержки демократии (равенства веса голосов)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файл записыватся объект `vector`, который содержит указатели на файл из кучи. При записы в файл и потом считывании происходит дублирование указателей на одно и то-же место в памяти. Деструктор вызывает исключение повторного удаления памяти.

В файл никогда нельзя писать указатели. Они указывают всего-лишь на временное местоположение объектов.

Comment: те "решенный пример" по моей ссылке ошибочный?

Comment: Он может работать **только** если класс **vector** *данного* компилятора хранит объекты во внутреннем массиве класса при маленьком его размере. И при этом **не** использует дополнительную память нигде. По-сути никогда не будет работать.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Пролежал ответ 10 лет однако...Я догадывался, что трабла в контейнерах. Не было четкости в понимании проблемы - не Степанов я.